# Auto renewable subscription: introductory pricing causes "This item is currently being modified. Please try again later."

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have implemented an in-app purchase of auto renewable subscription in my iOS app. It is working fine, users can make purchases no worries.

The trouble is when I add [introductory pricing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in_app_purchase/offering_introductory_pricing_in_your_app) to the product, when I try a test purchase I then get the error "This item is currently being modified. Please try again later."

I am testing through TestFlight beta testing as an internal tester, this method of testing works fine for regular priced products, but those with introductory pricing associated with them result in an error.

Has anyone come across a fix for this? Is it a known issue?

Other SO questions have suggested this can happen when Apple adjusts their pricing, however this has happened several months ago and again now, and I would assume regular pricing would be effected in that case.

Cheers

Comment: Hi Mitchell, have u solve this? we are seeing this as well...Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Bonan I still see this behaviour when beta testing, however when the app is deployed to the app store the purchase seems to work fine... very annoying

Comment: yeah we deployed too and seems it's fine now. Thanks very much!